# UDP Client with Socket Programming Message Error?

Tags: python, c, udp, packet, bsd

Hello l am new to BSD Socket API programming. I followed the UDP client example on the Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) and l am encountering a strange issue. The packets arrive at my server, but the message inside is cut off. I am looking for the terminology for this problem, and a clue to resolve this issue. Thank you for the assistance.

C Function:

```
void udp_client_task() { 
    while(1) { 
          int sock; struct sockaddr_in sa; char buffer[200];

          strcpy(buffer,"My World NEO! This is My World!");

          /* create an Internet, datagram, socket using UDP */
          sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
          if (sock == -1) {
              /* if socket failed to initialize, exit */
              break;
          }

          /* Zero out socket address */
          memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);

          /* The address is IPv4 */
          sa.sin_family = AF_INET;

           /* IPv4 addresses is a uint32_t, convert octets to the appropriate value */    
          sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.5");

          /* sockets are unsigned shorts, htons(x) ensures x is in network byte order */
          sa.sin_port = htons(139);

          bytes_sent = sendto(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof sa);

         // osDelay(500);
          close(sock); /* close the socket */
}
```

Python UDP Server:

```py
import socket
from datetime import datetime


class UDP_Server():

    def __init__(self, single_group, port_receive):

        self.single_group = single_group
        self.port_receive = port_receive

    def configure_receive_server(self):

        # Define the buffer size for this function
        size_buffer = 1024

        # Print start of function
        msg = 'UDP Receive Inputs: Single Group - {0} ; Port (Receive From) - {1} ; Buffer Size - {2}'.format(self.single_group, self.port_receive, size_buffer)
        print(msg)

        # Open a UDP socket
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        print("Socket created...")

        # Allow port reuse
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        print("Socket allowed reuse...")

        # Bind IP Address to Port
        print("Binding the IP: {0}".format(self.single_group))
        sock.bind((self.single_group, self.port_receive))

        while True:
            print("------ New Loop ------")
            # Receive the client packet along with the address it is coming from
            message, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print("{0}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")))
            msg = 'UDP message received from address - {0} ; \nMessage - {1} ; \nMessage Length - {2}'.format(address, message, len(message))
            print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Define constants
    UDP_IP = "192.168.0.5"
    # UDP_group = "192.168.0.5"
    port_receive_tlm = 139
    # port_receive_tlm = 139

    # Initialize the class
    commander = UDP_Server(single_group=UDP_IP,
                    port_receive=port_receive_tlm)


    # Listen for a response
    # NOTE: This will exit after a certain number of attempts
    commander.configure_receive_server()
```

[image]

Comment: Show the receiving code. Probaby your receive buffer is too small.

Comment: Ok l just pasted the receiving code.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Try printing the value of `bytes_sent` in the C program and see what you get.  Also, make the C program a complete program, not just one function.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but you should format `message` with `message_as_string = message.decode("utf8")` before printing it. I don't think that's the cause for your truncation issue, but it wouldn't hurt

Comment: Aside from a few nuances related to socket programming, your code looks fine with regards to sending and receiving. What I don't get is that your message length at send time is `strlen(buffer)`, but your receive side is indicating a length of 33 bytes.  The code you are showing above is exactly the same code you are experiencing the truncated message issue with, yes?

Comment: And after I compiled your code and adapted to work on my computer, it works fine.  Prints the whole message.  I'm out.

Comment: Thank you selbie and the others for the help.